# Nesting HTML form alternative

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angularjs

I am trying to add an upload module ([ngUpload](https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload)) to my code. 
The problem is that ngUpload uses a HTML form and I need to place it within another HTML form for a layout purpose. This is what my setup looks like:

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
<div class="form-group addscript">
...
    <form ng-upload="uploader(content)" method="post" action="/upload" name="foo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p class="help-block"><input type="file" name="file"></p>
      <a href='javascript:void(0)' class="upload-submit" ng-click="saveData()">Upload</a> 
    </form>
...
</div>
</form>
```

And I know that I can't nest HTML forms, so what is the easiest way to solve this? 
Maybe there is a way to "inject" the upload form to the outer form, without violating the nesting forms concept?

Comment: If you're using AJAX, you don't need a form at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angularjs you CAN nest forms like this:

```
<form name="form1">
    <div ng-form="" name="form2">
    </form>
</form>
```

`ngForm` acts exactly like actual `form`

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with angular, but isn't this invalid xml?

Comment: `ng-form` exists for the purpose of nesting forms. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Unfortunately I can't make the ngUpload directive work with ngForm (only seems to work inside i form tag). So I think I have to find another way to do it.

Comment: If any one else are struggling with ngUpload, I found this module which seemed to do the trick:
https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload
as it is not directly dependent on a native HTML form.